# Pandas - select columns based on datatypes in subset

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe of Pandas, some columns that are numeric, like float; some are non-numeric, like object. We want to drop those row whose numeric columns are NaN, but not those whose non-numeric ones are NaN.

For example, for a df with four columns: A, B, C, and D. The datatype of A and C is Object, and the datatype of B and D is Float.

```
**A(Object)   B(Float)C(Object)   D(Float)**

Apple       NaN     String1     1.0
Orange      2.0     NaN         3.0
Banana      4.0     String2     5.0
NaN         1.0     String3     2.0
Pear        NaN     String4     3.0
Melon       2.0     String5     NaN
```

And we'll only remove those rows in which some numeric columns(float) are NaN, and those rows in which some non-numeric columns(Object) are NaN should NOT be removed.

The final result will be as the following:

```
**A(Object)   B(Float)C(Object)   D(Float)**

Orange      2.0     NaN         3.0
Banana      4.0     String2     5.0
NaN         1.0     String3     2.0
```

My steps are:

1. check which columns' datatypes are numeric, like Float: we get 'B' and 'D' columns as their datatypes are Float;
2. use subset to drop those rows including NaN in numeric columns by method dropna.

The following is the code:

```
df = penguins.dropna(0, how='any', subset=['B','D'])
```

But if the amount of the numeric columns is extremely large, this code will be extremely long, sometimes almost impossible.

So how to select those columns based on their datatypes in subset=[]?

I'm considering lambda and pipeline, but I'm not quite sure.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select_dtypes` like this:

```
df[df.select_dtypes(include='number').notna().all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
        A    B        C    D
1  Orange  2.0      NaN  3.0
2  Banana  4.0  String2  5.0
3     NaN  1.0  String3  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[df['B'].notna()]
df = df[df['D'].notna()]
```